# Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to implement a function using Page in jpa, but I keep getting an IllegalArgumentException for my Page object I don't quite understand, I know the error says I'm trying to pass something that's not supported, but I can't find exactly why.

Here's my code:
Service

```
public Page<VolumeMeasurerRegistries> getVolumeMeasurerRegistries(ResquestVolumeMeasurerRegistries resquestVolumeMeasurerRegistries) throws VolumeMeasurerRegisterException {
    try {
        return volumeMeasurerRegisterRepository.findByEquipmentIdEquipmentAndMeasuredTimeLessThanEqualAndMeasuredTimeGreaterThanEqual(
                resquestVolumeMeasurerRegistries.getIdEquipment() != null ? UUID.fromString(resquestVolumeMeasurerRegistries.getIdEquipment()) : null,
                format.parse(resquestVolumeMeasurerRegistries.getFilterStartDate()),
                format.parse(resquestVolumeMeasurerRegistries.getFilterEndDate()),
                PageRequest.of(
                      resquestVolumeMeasurerRegistries.getVolumeMeasurerRegisterDisplayPage(),
                      resquestVolumeMeasurerRegistries.getVolumeMeasurerRegisterDisplayAmount()));

    } catch (Exception getSomeException) {
        //Do something
    }

}
```

And this is my repository function:

```
public interface VolumeMeasurerRegistriesRepository extends JpaRepository<VolumeMeasurerRegistries, UUID> {

     @Query(value = "SELECT vmr FROM VolumeMeasurerRegistries vmr "
        + "WHERE (:idEquipment is null or vmr.Equipment.idEquipment = :idEquipment) "
        + "AND (:startTime is null or vmr.measuredTime >= :startTime) "
        + "AND (:endTime is null or vmr.measuredTime <= :endTime) ", nativeQuery = false)
     Page<VolumeMeasurerRegistries> findByEquipmentIdEquipmentAndMeasuredTimeLessThanEqualAndMeasuredTimeGreaterThanEqual(
        @Nullable @Param("idEquipment") UUID idEquipment,
        @Nullable @Param("startTime") Date startTime, 
        @Nullable @Param("endTime") Date endTime, 
        @Nullable Pageable pageable);
  }
```

And the error I get:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'volumeMeasurerRegistriesRepository':
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for
> method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page
> mx.ssf.sicom.repositories.VolumeMeasurerRegistriesRepository.findByEquipmentIdEquipmentAndMeasuredTimeLessThanEqualAndMeasuredTimeGreaterThanEqual(java.util.UUID,java.util.Date,java.util.Date,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace

Comment: Does the query run if you execute it explicitly using JPA Query API? Something like this:

    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT ...");

    q.setParameter("idEquipment", ...); // etc

    q.getResultList();